# How can i be able to convert java crossword puzzle code to javafx gui

Tags: java

Hi i have just started learning java programming, i have been trying to convert the gui of the crossword puzzle below with a javafx gui but it seems like there is quite a lot of errors when i transfer the codes to javafx. please help what can i do. please help.

package mercy;

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Mercy
{
    JFrame frame=new JFrame("Crossword Puzzle"); //creates frame
    JButton[][] grid; //names the grid of buttons

    static final String letters[] = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};

    String words[] = null;

    // Linked lists to hold the letters
    ArrayList  value = null;
    ArrayList  listXY = null;
    ArrayList  selectedButtons = null;

    String formedWord = "";
    int wordsFound = 0;

   private JPanel centerPanel = null;
    private JPanel bottomPanel = null;
    private JButton checkWord = null;
    private JButton clearSelection = null;
        private JButton exit=null;

    public Mercy(int width, int length, String words[])
    {    
        this.words = words;
        //frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(width,length)); //set layout
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(width, length));

        bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

         checkWord = new JButton("Check Word");
        clearSelection = new JButton("Clear Selection");
        exit = new JButton("Exit Game");
        grid=new JButton[width][length]; //allocate the size of grid

        value = new ArrayList();
        listXY = new ArrayList();
        selectedButtons = new ArrayList();

        // Populate the grid with # to indicate empty slots
       for(int y=0; y<20; y++)
        {
            for(int x=0; x<20; x++)
            {
                final JButton button = new JButton("#");

                grid[x][y] = button;

                button.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
                    formedWord = formedWord+(button.getLabel());
                   button.setEnabled(false);
                    selectedButtons.add(button);
                    });

                //frame.add(grid[x][y]); //adds button to grid
                centerPanel.add(grid[x][y]);
                frame.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                value.add("#");
                listXY.add(""+x+","+y); // put the x,y coordinate in the list
            }
        }

        checkWord.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The word: "+formedWord+" "+wordExist(formedWord));
            checkIfGameOver();
            });

        clearSelection.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            formedWord = "";
            enableAllButtons();
            clearSelectedButtons();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Selected letters cleared");
            });
        bottomPanel.add(checkWord);
        bottomPanel.add(clearSelection);
        bottomPanel.add(exit);
        frame.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // Set the default close operation
        frame.pack(); //sets appropriate size for frame
        frame.setVisible(true); //makes frame visible     
    }

    public void placeWords()
    {
        int length = words.length;

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            placeWord(words[i]);
        }

        populateWithRandom();
    }

    public String wordExist(String word)
    {
        String exist = "does not exist";

        for (String word1 : words) {
            if (word1.equals(word)) {
                exist = "exists";
                formedWord = "";
                wordsFound++;
                markWordFound();
                clearSelectedButtons();
            }
        }

        return exist;
    }

    public void checkIfGameOver()
    {
        if(wordsFound == words.length)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "GAME OVER");
        }
    }

    public void clearSelectedButtons()
    {
        selectedButtons.stream().map((_item) -> {
            //selectedButtons.remove(i);
            selectedButtons = null;
            return _item;
        }).forEachOrdered((_item) -> {
            selectedButtons = new ArrayList();
        });
    }

    public void markWordFound()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < selectedButtons.size(); i++)
        {
            JButton button = (JButton) selectedButtons.get(i);
            button.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }
    }

    public void enableAllButtons()
    {
        for(int y=0; y<20; y++)
        {
            for(int x=0; x<20; x++)
            {
                grid[x][y].setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    }

    public void placeWord(String word)
    {   
        int wordLength = word.length();
        int randomX = 0;
        int randomY = 0;

        int startPointChange = 0;
        while(startPointChange < 4)
        {
            randomX = getRandomNumber(19);
            randomY = getRandomNumber(19);

            int direction = getRandomNumber(3);

            int directionsChange = 0; // Number of times tried fitting the word in different directions starting from the given start point
            while(directionsChange < 4)
            {
                if(canWordFit(wordLength, direction, randomX, randomY))
                {
                    if(!canWordOverlap(word, direction, randomX, randomY))
                    {
                        insertWord(word, direction, randomX, randomY);

                        startPointChange = 4;
                        break;
                    }

                    directionsChange++;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Change the direction and try fitting the word
                    direction = getRandomNumber(3); 

                    directionsChange++;
                }
            }

            // For the ith run, and you still cannot insert a word despite changing the directions? Consider changing the start point!          
            startPointChange++;
        }
    }

    public boolean canWordFit(int wordLength, int direction, int startX, int startY)
    {
        boolean canFit = false;

        switch (direction) {
            case 1:
                canFit = (startX + wordLength) < 19;
                break;
            case 2:
                canFit = (startX - wordLength) > 0;
                break;
            case 3:
                canFit = (startY + wordLength) < 19;
                break;
            case 4:
                canFit = (startY - wordLength) > 0;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return canFit;
    }

    /*
    * This method will check if the given word will overlap with any other word in a given direction starting from the given start point
    * If the given letter in the given coordinate match an existing letter, overlook.
    */
    public boolean canWordOverlap(String word, int direction, int startX, int startY)
    {
        boolean canOverlap = false;

        switch (direction) {
            case 1:
                {
                    int index = 0;
                    for(int x=startX; x < (startX + word.length()); x++)
                    {
                        String theValue = value.get(listXY.indexOf(""+x+","+startY)).toString();

                        if(matchValue(theValue, ""+word.charAt(index)) == false)
                        {
                            canOverlap = true;
                        }

                        System.out.println("Direction: "+direction+" - VALUE: "+theValue+" - "+word.charAt(index) + " - CanOverlap "+canOverlap);

                        index++;
                    }       break;
                }
            case 2:
                {
                    int index = 0;
                    for(int x=startX; x > (startX - word.length()); x--)
                    {
                        String theValue = value.get(listXY.indexOf(""+x+","+startY)).toString();

                        if(matchValue(theValue, ""+word.charAt(index)) == false)
                        {
                            canOverlap = true;
                        }

                        System.out.println("Direction: "+direction+" - VALUE: "+theValue+" - "+word.charAt(index) + " - CanOverlap "+canOverlap);

                        index++;
                    }       break;
                }
            case 3:
                {
                    int index = 0;
                    for(int y=startY; y < (startY + word.length()); y++)
                    {
                        String theValue = value.get(listXY.indexOf(""+startX+","+y)).toString();

                        if(matchValue(theValue, ""+word.charAt(index)) == false)
                        {
                            canOverlap = true;
                        }

                        System.out.println("Direction: "+direction+" - VALUE: "+theValue+" - "+word.charAt(index) + " - CanOverlap "+canOverlap);

                        index++;
                    }       break;
                }
            case 4:
                {
                    int index = 0;
                    for(int y=startY; y < (startY - word.length()); y--)
                    {
                        String theValue = value.get(listXY.indexOf(""+startX+","+y)).toString();

                        if(matchValue(theValue, ""+word.charAt(index)) == false)
                        {
                            canOverlap = true;
                        }

                        System.out.println("Direction: "+direction+" - VALUE: "+theValue+" - "+word.charAt(index) + " - CanOverlap "+canOverlap);

                        index++;
                    }       break;
                }
            default:
                break;
        }

        return canOverlap;
    }

    public boolean matchValue(String existing, String target) 
    {
        boolean matching = false;
        if(existing.equals("#") || existing.equals(target))
        {
            matching = true;
        }

        return matching;
    }

    public void insertWord(String word, int direction, int startX, int startY)
    {    
        System.out.println("Direction: "+direction+" - StartX: "+startX+" - StartY: "+startY); 

        switch (direction) {
            case 1:
                {
                    int index = 0;
                    for(int x=startX; x < (startX + word.length()); x++)
                    {
                        grid[x][startY].setLabel(""+word.charAt(index)); // Rename the # place holder with the letter from the word on the UI

                        value.set(listXY.indexOf(""+x+","+startY), ""+word.charAt(index)); // Rename the # place holder with the letter from the word in the linked list

                        //grid[x][startY].setBackground(Color.red);
                        index++;
                    }       break;
                }
            case 2:
                {
                    int index = 0;
                    for(int x=startX; x > (startX - word.length()); x--)
                    {
                        grid[x][startY].setLabel(""+word.charAt(index)); // Rename the # place holder with the letter from the word on the UI

                        value.set(listXY.indexOf(""+x+","+startY), ""+word.charAt(index)); // Rename the # place holder with the letter from the word in the linked list

                        //grid[x][startY].setBackground(Color.red);
                        index++;
                    }       break;
                }
            case 3:
                {
                    int index = 0;
                    for(int y=startY; y < (startY + word.length()); y++)
                    {
                        grid[startX][y].setLabel(""+word.charAt(index)); // Rename the # place holder with the letter from the word on the UI

                        value.set(listXY.indexOf(""+startX+","+y), ""+word.charAt(index)); // Rename the # place holder with the letter from the word in the linked list

                        //grid[startX][y].setBackground(Color.red);
                        index++;
                    }       break;
                }
            case 4:
                {
                    int index = 0;
                    for(int y=startY; y < (startY - word.length()); y--)
                    {
                        grid[startX][y].setLabel(""+word.charAt(index)); // Rename the # place holder with the letter from the word on the UI

                        value.set(listXY.indexOf(""+startX+","+y), ""+word.charAt(index)); // Rename the # place holder with the letter from the word in the linked list

                        //grid[startX][y].setBackground(Color.red);
                        index++;
                    }       break;
                }
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public void populateWithRandom()
    {
        for(int y=0; y<20; y++)
        {
            for(int x=0; x<20; x++)
            {
                if(grid[x][y].getLabel().equals("#"))
                {
                    grid[x][y].setLabel(letters[getRandomNumber(25)]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int getRandomNumber(int max)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        return rand.nextInt(max) + 1;
    }

    public void displayGrid()
    {
        for(int y=0; y<20; y++)
         {
             for(int x=0; x<20; x++)
             {
                 System.out.print(grid[x][y]);
             }
         }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        // Read words from the file and start the system
        String words[] = null;

        String line = "";
        File Myf = new File("C:\\CrossWord.txt");

        BufferedReader Myin;
        try
        {
            Myin = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Myf));
            line = Myin.readLine();

            words = line.split(",");
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
         }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
        }

        Mercy test = new Mercy(20,20, words);       
        test.placeWords();
    }   
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? post your JavaFx code

Comment: Hi Oswald i just copy pasted the code as it is to a new javafx project. i thought that could work but it did not.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. JavaFx is a different framework altogether just like Swings, AWT etc, you need to use Javafx functions for it to work, you simply cannot use  awt, swing in javafx, google how a simple javafx application is wriiten

Comment: what i wanted for the program is to convert the interface of the game from a java interface to a javafx interface. if that is possible

Comment: the game is coded using java.

Comment: Yes, for that you would have to use Javafx panels, Panes, buttons instead of JFrame, JPanel etc

Comment: kindly help with a small example on that please.

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You cannot just dump hundreds of lines of code and hope people will go through it all and fix it. If you're not familiar with javaFx, then google it and read some tutorials.